# PHP: Methods of the class don't work when including php file in another one

Tags: php, class, object

I have created a class and saved the file as class.Address.inc.php
which has the following structure :

```
<?php 
class Address {
public $street_address_1;
public $street_address_2;
public $city_name;
public $subdivision_name;
public $postal_code;
public $country_name;
//display an address in html
public function display() {
    $output='';
    //Street Address
    $output .=$this->street_address_1;
    if($this->street_address_2) {
    $output .= '<br/>'. $this->street_address_2;
     }
    //City, Subdivision, Postal Code
    $output.='<br/>';
    $output.= $this->city_name. ','. $this->subdivision_name;
    $output.= ' '.$this->postal_code;
    //Country
    $output.='<br/>';
    $output.= $this->country_name;

    return $output;
}

}
```

and in my demo.php file, I have created an instance of that class :

```
<?php
require 'class.Address.inc';
echo '<h2> Instanitation Address </h2>';
$address = new Address;
$address->street_address_1 ='555 Fake Street';
$address->city_name = 'Townvile';
$address->subdivision_name ='State';
$address->postal_code ='12345';
$address->country_name='US';
echo '<h2> Displaying Address </h2>';
echo $address->display();
?>
```

I get the following error in the browser :

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Address::display() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dwwphp\demo.php on line 7.
```

What seems to be causing the problem?

Comment: Please note that when I put all of php code into one file without using "require", it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'class.Address.inc';
```

should be

```
require 'class.Address.inc.php';
```

Comment: Oops :) the guy in the tutorial didn't do that and he didn't face any errors. Thanks it worked.